# iOS record video with camera and UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, video, swift, camera

I'm trying to have an `UIImagePickerController` which allows to take photo with a simple touch and record video with a long touch as Snapchat.

This is my `UIImagePickerController` subclass :

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class ImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var takeButton : UIButton

    override init ()
    {
        takeButton = UIButton ();
        super.init()

        self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self.allowsEditing = false
        self.showsCameraControls = false
        self.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie, kUTTypeImage]
        self.videoMaximumDuration = 10
        self.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.TypeMedium;

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

        self.cameraOverlayView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);


        takeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 100, 100)
        takeButton.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height - 60);
        takeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "takeButton.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        takeButton.addTarget(self, action: "takePicture:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
        {
            let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("holdAction:"))
            recognizer.delegate = self
            takeButton.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        }

        self.cameraOverlayView?.clipsToBounds = true;
        self.cameraOverlayView?.addSubview(takeButton)
    }

    func takePicture(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        self.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Photo;
        self.takePicture()
    }

    func holdAction(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        self.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Video;
        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
        {
            self.startVideoCapture()
            println("Video capturing...")
        }
        else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
        {
            self.stopVideoCapture()
            println("End recording !");
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        takeButton = UIButton ();
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
        takeButton = UIButton ();
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
}
```

No problem fro the picture part but for the video work it's only work the second time. With the first touch I have always one of these errors :

- `Camera: ignoring _previewStarted because waiting for session to be rebuilt`
- `UIImagePickerController: requested to stop video capture before recording stopped`
- `UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to stop video capture; camera is not currently capturing` video
- UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to change camera mode; camera is capturing a video.

Do you have an idea for my problem ?

Comment: Could you please show how did you solve long touch for video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the UIImagePickerController is a very high-level API so we juste have to drop down a level and use **AVFoundation** and start a **AVCaptureSession** to do this. Hope it's help !

A little swift tutorial with AVFoundation can found here : http://jamesonquave.com/blog/taking-control-of-the-iphone-camera-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

Thanks to *reidnez* from raywenderlich.com !